# How to extract year from an excel cell containing an old date?

Tags: excel, date

When I have a date like 2/12/2022 in a cell in an excel document (say in the cell A1),

`=year(A1)`

gives 2022, but this does not work for a date like 2/12/1875.
Indeed it returns `#Value!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2/12/1875 is before the beginning of the [date system in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487#:%7E:text=Excel%20supports%20two%20date%20systems,on%20the%201900%20date%20system.).
To see the beginning, as per your system, write `1` and format as a date:

[image]

In general, using the `=YEAR()` formula is not possible before the beginning of the first serial number, thus you should resort to other options. Like this one:

`=RIGHT(A2,4)`

or a more complicated one, that gives the last element in A2, separated by "/":

`=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("/",A2,SEARCH("/",A2,SEARCH("/",A2)+1)))`

Comment: Thank you, change `=RIGHT(A2;4)` to `=RIGHT(A2,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),,-1)
```

[image]